# How can you detect a socket has been closed while waiting on recv?

Tags: python, sockets

how can I detect that a socket I am currently listening at with `recv()` has been closed?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: My feeling is that if you have to ask that question, your code has a problem with race conditions.  For example, in a multithreaded program, if it is possible for another thread to call `close()` on your socket, then it's also possible that it (or some other thread) might call `socket()`, which could allocate a new/different socket with the same file descriptor as your thread's old socket, all before your thread realizes anything has happened.  Now your thread is still using a valid socket, but it's a different socket entirely!  It's a real nightmare to debug that sort of thing.

Comment: ^ note my comment above is relevant if you are talking about the **socket** being closed, which is a separate thing from the **TCP connection** being closed.  If you meant the latter, let me know and I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

`socket.recv()` will return an empty byte array if the peer has closed the connection gracefully. Otherwise it will raise an error.

Comment: Hi, I'm guessing your answer refers to a case `recv` is being called after the socket has closed, I'm having trouble with detecting it while listening. I have a client who suppose to exit the program it a `catch` block when the socket is being closed, but he never gets there.

Comment: @Yohai "*I'm guessing your answer refers to a case recv is being called after the socket has closed*" - no. It doesn't matter whether the socket is closed before or while `recv` is waiting, the result is the same. "*I'm having trouble with detecting it while listening*" - my answer covers that case. "*I have a client who suppose to exit the program it a catch block when the socket is being closed, but he never gets there.*" - read my answer. An exception is not the only possible result.